# rotating package, change rotation of a single sideways table

Tags: rotating, sidewaystable

The question about how to force rotation of `sidewaystable` or `sidewaysfigure` has been asked several times and the answer is always "use the package `rotating` with option `figuresleft` or `figuresright` or `clockwise`, etc.".

This is good practice since it forces the same behavior all along the book.

But I need an exception. I have a sideways table that is two pages long, so I'm splitting it between an even page and an odd page. But of course for this to happen I need the two tables to be oriented in the same way. But I don't want to change the global behavior of `sideways` environments either, this should be exceptional.

How I can change the rotation of a single `sidewaystable` environment without using a package option?

(I tried to use `counterclockwise` as an environment option but it didn't worked…)

Following advice by Ulrike, here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{48}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{This is the first part of the table on the even page}

\bigskip

Stuff that needs to be written from bottom to top.

\end{sidewaystable}

\newpage

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{This is the second part of the table on the odd page}

\bigskip

Stuff that also needs to be written from bottom to top.

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

The goal is to have the even-page sideways table (page 48) displaying text from bottom to top, just like the odd-page sideways table, without changing the global package option.

Comment: it would help if you would make a short example with some dummy images. That makes it much easier to test a solution.

Comment: The other choice is to use \afterpage and landscape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{48}
\makeatletter \@rot@twosidefalse \makeatother

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{This is the first part of the table on the even page}

\bigskip

Stuff that needs to be written from bottom to top.

\end{sidewaystable}

\newpage
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{This is the second part of the table on the odd page}

\bigskip

Stuff that also needs to be written from bottom to top.

\end{sidewaystable}

\makeatletter \@rot@twosidetrue \makeatother

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Ulrike!!!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use `landscape` pages encapsulated in `\afterpage{...}` instead of two consecutive `sidewaystable`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{page}{46}
\begin{document}

\lipsum
\afterpage{%
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
\caption{This is the first part of the table on the even page}

\bigskip
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{table}

\clearpage

\begin{table}
\caption{This is the second part of the table on the odd page}

\bigskip
\lipsum[3-4]

\end{table}
\end{landscape}
}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]